# How to hide 'show' page

Tags: php, laravel

## Error in show.blade.php

Hello! I want to hide or do something which help me to avoid error from show.blade.php

So when i try to get admin/{$id} in URL that work but, when i write admin/show - there is error, so i don't want to get error on this page.
What i must to do for this, to fix this thing. (Or just hide if it is a good idea).

```
 public function show($id)
    {
          $products = Product::find($id);

          return view('admins.product.show')->with('products', $products);  
    }
```

This is error in /admin/show ('if i fix this, i won't get my dates from db)

> Trying to get property 'photo' of non-object

```
@extends('admins.layout.master')
@section('content')

<div class="_TwoBlock">
<div class="_MainBlock">


    <div class="_Photo">
        <img src="{{asset('upload/'.$products->photo)}}" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>



    <div class="_title">
        <div class="title">
            <p style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">{{$products->title}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="_Price">
    <p class ="Price">RUB: {{$products->price}}</p>
</div>
</div>
<!-- ------------------------------------------------ -->
<div class="_description">

    <p>{{$products->description}}</p>

</div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this, to see if it is what you are trying to achieve.

```
public function show($id)
{
    $product = Product::find($id);

    abort_unless($product, 404); //Product not found
    ...
}
```

I do this because if you are going to load any product value that does not exist, you will have to check for each of them. And if it does not exist, it does not make much sense to do those checks.
I think it is the most optimal, although of course, everything depends on what you want to achieve.

I have also changed the name of the variable, since it is only going to obtain a product.

```
$products
```

by

```
$product
```

A cordial greeting.